# Android database search data on EditText TextChange

Tags: android, database, search, android-sqlite

I am building an android application with a database that contains more than 20,000 entries.

When i retrieve data from the database, especially when searching for data, it seems to be working slow.

Especially, when i search data based on an `editText`. Every time `editText` `TextChange()`, i  query :

`Select * from mytable where data='mydata'`

And it runs slowly.
I really don't know how to make it work faster.

Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: Do you have an index on data field?

Comment: yes , my database fields (_id, word)

Comment: is `word` the column you're searching on?

Comment: yes, i am searching for word

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index on just that column to make selection work faster. If your column is the second one in an existing index, this index cannot be used most efficiently.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mytable_word ON mytable(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you initialize db connection every time? 
Try to add pagination. it's make your app faster.

Comment: I only connect it at start of my application. but it still runs slow, especially, when i search data from edittext